# Filtrar linhas no pandas por uma lista

Tags: python, pandas

Dado o dataframe abaixo, gostaria de filtrar os dados das linhas em função da lista 'listaFiltro'.

```
    nome    valor
0   foo     2
1   bar     3
2   fiz     2
3   zaz     5
4   foo     6
5   far     7
6   bar     2
7   fiz     9
8   zoo     6
9   boo     3
10  zuz     8
11  zuz     10

listaFiltro = ['fiz', 'zoo', 'far']
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda dos amigos!

Comment: Já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 1):

De uma maneira bem simplificada, voce pode utilizar isso:

```
def listaFiltro(dataframe, primeiro, segundo, terceiro):
       return dataframe[(dataframe['nome']==primeiro) | (dataframe['nome'] == segundo) | (dataframe['nome'] == terceiro)]
df_teste = listaFiltro('fiz', 'zoo', 'far')
df_teste
```

***Exemplo 2:***

Nesse caso para passar uma lista variável, você pode utilizar a função **isin** conforme está abaixo.

```
def listaFiltro(dataframe, valores):
    return dataframe.loc[dataframe['nome'].isin(valores)]
lista = ['fiz', 'zoo', 'far']
dfteste = listaFiltro(df, lista)
dfteste
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo! Porém, imagine uma listaFiltro com 20 itens? Não existe no panas algo como : df[filter(itens=listaFiltro, axis=0) ], mas que funcionasse logicamente?

Comment: mrzappabr, resposta ajustada a necessidade, acredito que seja isto que esteja buscando.

Comment: Exatamente Clayton, bem mais simples. Poderia ter feito de diversas outras maneiras, mas você deve concordar que esta ultima é a mais "elegante". Tentei dar um voto na sua resposta mas, como sou novato, não consegui. De qualquer forma, fica o meu agradecimento por sua ajuda.

Comment: Claro muito mais elegante, e digamos 'Correta' rs. Sem problema nenhum amigo, o importante é que funcionou e é isso que vale. Se possível só marque a resposta como correta para que outras pessoas possam ser auxiliadas.

Comment: Conforme eu já disse, infelizmente, não consigo votar. Mas eu dei um UP de qualquer forma. Abração Clayton !

Answer (score 0):

Para filtrar as linhas com base na lista 'listaFiltro', você pode usar o método .isin() do Pandas para verificar se o valor da coluna "nome" está presente na lista. O código a seguir faz isso:

```
import pandas as pd

# Criando o dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'nome': ['foo', 'bar', 'fiz', 'zaz', 'foo', 'far', 'bar', 'fiz', 'zoo', 'boo', 'zuz', 'zuz'],
  'valor': [2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2, 9, 6, 3, 8, 10]
})

# Criando a lista de filtro
listaFiltro = ['fiz', 'zoo', 'far']

# Filtrando as linhas com base na lista de filtro
df_filtrado = df[df['nome'].isin(listaFiltro)]

# Mostrando o resultado
print(df_filtrado)
```

A saída será:

```
   nome  valor
2  fiz   2
5  far   7
7  fiz   9
8  zoo   6
```

Answer (score -2):

Aproveitando o exemplo fornecido pelo Clayton, pode-se fazer diretamente, sem usar função:

`x = dfteste.loc[dfteste['nome'].isin(['fiz','zoo','far'])]
print(x)`

Comment: Saudações Daniel, parece que isso já foi apresentado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/309055/5878).  Tem alguma outra consideração a mais que possa valorizar a discussão?