# Selecionar linhas de DataFrame baseado em lista de valores para uma coluna

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um DataFrame com mais de 5 mil linhas e mais de 20 colunas.

Quero selecionar apenas algumas linhas, segundo critério de match das colunas com valores específicos

```
SELECT *
FROM dataframe
WHERE colume_name = lista_de_valores
```

isto é

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('arquivo.csv', encoding = "utf-8-sig", sep=",")  
print(df.columns)

## Index(['idx', 'prod', 'number', 'date', ..., 'stockN'], dtype='object')
```

O que preciso é criar um novo `df2`, com todas as linhas em que `'stockN'` é igual a um valor, mantendo algumas colunas

```
lista_de_valores = {'stockN':['169', ..., '1390', '1464', '157', '3833']} # mais de 20 valores
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lista_de_valores, columns= ['idx', 'date', 'stockN'])
```

Mas apesar do `'stockN'` vir correto, o DataFrame vem com `nan` nas outras colunas selecionadas. O que tô errando aqui?

Valeu desde já!

Comment: você pode compartilhar a base de dados?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Filtrar linhas no pandas por uma lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309037/filtrar-linhas-no-pandas-por-uma-lista)

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você quer fazer um filtro. Aqui você pode consultar melhor a documentação [pandas.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

Tem ótimos exemplos, por exemplo, este é exatamente o que você precisa:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])),
...                   index=['mouse', 'rabbit'],
...                   columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
>>> df
        one  two  three
mouse     1    2      3
rabbit    4    5      6
```

Assim também pode ser mais útil para você.

```
>>> # select rows containing 'bbi'
>>> df.filter(like='bbi', axis=0)
         one  two  three
rabbit    4    5      6
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução é utilizar o método `isin()`

### Criando DataFrame de teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'prod':["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"], 'number':[1,1,1,5,5,5,5,1,1,1], 'stockN':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})

>>> df
  prod  number  stockN
0    a       1       1
1    b       1       2
2    c       1       3
3    d       5       4
4    e       5       5
5    f       5       6
6    g       5       7
7    h       1       8
8    i       1       9
9    j       1      10
```

### Criando query

```
>>> query = [4,5,6,7]

>>> df['stockN'].isin(query)   # Somente para verificar o resultado
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: stockN, dtype: bool
```

### Atribuindo a um novo DataFrame

```
>>> df2 = df[df['stockN'].isin(query)]

>>> print(df2)

  prod  number  stockN
3    d       5       4
4    e       5       5
5    f       5       6
6    g       5       7
```